# JGit: Status of remote repository

Tags: java, eclipse, git, github, jgit

I'm trying to get the status of a Git repository using JGit in Eclipse.
I found some examples here: [1](https://github.com/centic9/jgit-cookbook/blob/master/src/main/java/org/dstadler/jgit/porcelain/CloneRemoteRepository.java), [2](https://github.com/centic9/jgit-cookbook/blob/master/src/main/java/org/dstadler/jgit/porcelain/ShowStatus.java) and merged them:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.eclipse.jgit.api.Git;
import org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.GitAPIException;
import org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.InvalidRemoteException;
import org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.TransportException;
import org.eclipse.jgit.lib.Repository;
import org.eclipse.jgit.storage.file.FileRepositoryBuilder;
import org.eclipse.jgit.api.Status;

public class Main {

     private static final String REMOTE_URL = "https://github.com/github/testrepo.git";

        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InvalidRemoteException, TransportException, GitAPIException {
            // prepare a new folder for the cloned repository
            File localPath = File.createTempFile("TestGitRepository", "");
            localPath.delete();

            // then clone
            System.out.println("Cloning from " + REMOTE_URL + " to " + localPath);
            Git.cloneRepository()
                    .setURI(REMOTE_URL)
                    .setDirectory(localPath)
                    .call();

            // now open the created repository
            FileRepositoryBuilder builder = new FileRepositoryBuilder();
            Repository repository = builder.setGitDir(localPath)
                    .readEnvironment() // scan environment GIT_* variables
                    .findGitDir() // scan up the file system tree
                    .build();

            System.out.println("Having repository: " + repository.getDirectory());

            Status status = new Git(repository).status().call();
            System.out.println("Added: " + status.getAdded());
            System.out.println("Changed: " + status.getChanged());
            System.out.println("Conflicting: " + status.getConflicting());
            System.out.println("ConflictingStageState: " + status.getConflictingStageState());
            System.out.println("IgnoredNotInIndex: " + status.getIgnoredNotInIndex());
            System.out.println("Missing: " + status.getMissing());
            System.out.println("Modified: " + status.getModified());
            System.out.println("Removed: " + status.getRemoved());
            System.out.println("Untracked: " + status.getUntracked());
            System.out.println("UntrackedFolders: " + status.getUntrackedFolders());

            repository.close();
        }
}
```

But I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.eclipse.jgit.errors.NoWorkTreeException: Bare Repository has neither a working tree, nor an index
    at org.eclipse.jgit.lib.Repository.getWorkTree(Repository.java:1245)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.treewalk.FileTreeIterator.<init>(FileTreeIterator.java:88)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.StatusCommand.call(StatusCommand.java:126)
    at Main.main(Main.java:38)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you replace the FileRepositoryBuilder part of your snippet with the lines below, the snippet will work.

```
Git git = Git.open( localPath );
Repository repository = git.getRepository();
```

Note that your snippet sets the GitDir of the builder to `localPath`, but the local path denotes the work directory of the just cloned repository.

Comment: Thanks, I don't get an error anymore! Do you also know, why I get only empty results, like: `Added: []
Changed: []
Conflicting: []...`

Comment: What would you expect? The results are empty because on a freshly cloned repository there is no difference between the work dir, the index and the HEAD commit. Please make sure that you understand [git status](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-status.html).

Comment: Then how can I get the results from the actual directory, not the cloned one? I just need things like "name, size, date, etc." of the files.

Comment: I am afraid I don't quite understand what 'results from the actual directory` means. 

Please note that Git can only operate on local repositories. If you whish to list all files of a remote directory you first have to create a clone. Once you have a local repository, you can use `FileTreeIterator` to iterate over all files in the work directory.